# How do I bridge my Westell 9100 with another router?

Tags: router, bridge

I switched ISPs, and the new router/modem they gave me is a Westell 9100 VM60-10. I'm having all sorts of wireless problems with it, so I'd like to use it as a simple data bridge to my old router (which worked great). I can't seem to find any support on this, the closest I've come is [this](http://www.dslreports.com/faq/13600), but it deals with an older model and the setup navigation is quite different.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for how to bridge this router?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to plug the old router's upstream (internet) port into one of the new router's downstream (computer) ports, then plug all of your computers into the old router.

Comment: That will work for connectivity, but it's not a true bridge. The old router will be behind the new router.

Comment: Correct.  Is there anything wrong with that?

Comment: I was worried about conflicts or external connectivity problems. But the computers that will be wireless probably won't run into anything like that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a true bridge, you can connect the downstream (computer) ports of the two routers.